# Cannot read serial number from ISO 7816 Smart Card under 22.04 with HID OMNIKEY 3121

Tags: smartcard

I know almost nothing about smart cards, and am desperately trying to learn. Google seems to return piles of information, but none that actually seem to target what I'm trying to do.

I want to write the string "HELLO WORLD" to a smart card and read it back using my code. Eventually I want to use this for a security app, but right now ... it's "crawl before walk"

I DO NOT want to use the cards to authenticate to the OS, e.g. at login. Right now ... just a first step ... ***I want to manipulate data on the card***

I have a HID OMNIKEY 3121 USB reader and a pack of 10 ISO7816 cards. I know for a fact that the reader is attached and (probably) working, because I can it (and the card) using pcsc_scan.

```
$ pcsc_scan
Using reader plug'n play mechanism
Scanning present readers...
0: HID Global OMNIKEY 3x21 Smart Card Reader [OMNIKEY 3x21 Smart Card Reader] 00 00
 
Thu Sep 21 07:15:50 2023
 Reader 0: HID Global OMNIKEY 3x21 Smart Card Reader [OMNIKEY 3x21 Smart Card Reader] 00 00
  Event number: 0
  Card state: Card inserted, 
  ATR: 3B 04 92 23 10 91

ATR: 3B 04 92 23 10 91
+ TS = 3B --> Direct Convention
+ T0 = 04, Y(1): 0000, K: 4 (historical bytes)
+ Historical bytes: 92 23 10 91
  Category indicator byte: 92 (proprietary format)

Possibly identified card (using /usr/share/pcsc/smartcard_list.txt):
3B 04 92 23 10 91
    Siemens SLE 4432/42 card
```

So let's see if I can even read the serial number off the card:

```
$ opensc-tool --serial
Using reader with a card: HID Global OMNIKEY 3x21 Smart Card Reader [OMNIKEY 3x21 Smart Card Reader] 00 00
sc_card_ctl(*, SC_CARDCTL_GET_SERIALNR, *) failed
```

It's difficult to even tell if I have the correct combination of reader and card. Again, I am very new to this technology. I'm not asking for a full-on lesson. Just ... please ... point me in the right direction. I've been at this for days.

Thanks in advance.